# Sending mail to all users with email in sql

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is this: I have a button that if clicked email will be sent to all customer in db that has email.

```
  public function Email() 
{
    $ind_connect=$this->OpenDB();
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT `E-mail` FROM `orders`");
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    $text ="Hi, How are you ?";

        if($num_rows>0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {


                if(isset($row['E-mail']))
                {
                        $tpl = file_get_contents("mail.eml");
                        $mail=$tpl;
                        $mail=strtr($mail,array(
                        "{TO}" =>$row['E-mail'],
                        "{TEXT}" =>$text,
                        ));


                    list($head,$body) = preg_split("/\r?\n\r?\n/s",$mail,2);
                    echo "$head <br> $body <br>";
                    mail("","",$body,$head);
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
```

That's on the html file

```
 Send Emails To Customers
               <br><br><button name='SendEmail' button type='submit'>Click Here</button>
```

and this is calling to the func

```
if(isset($_POST['SendEmail'])) 
    $db->Email();
```

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: `mail("","",$body,$head);` so you're e-mailing nobody, with no subject?

Comment: The quetsion is why its not working.and for now i just want to body.what i getting now is the button unclickable .i clicking and nothing happend

Comment: Why is what not working? The `button`? If so because you have no form.

Comment: still after adding Form ,not working .

Comment: Well adding the code you updated would be useful..

Comment: the only diffrent is i added <form> ..all the code in the first topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use correct HTML `form` element with `POST` method. Default the `GET` method is using (according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).

Replace this part of your code

```
<br><br><button name='SendEmail' button type='submit'>Click Here</button>
```

with this

```
<form method="post">
    <br><br><button type="submit" name="SendEmail">Click Here</form>
</form>
```